# IBM MQ (iSeries) - Completion Code Defaulting to Zero?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

we have a Windows c# application that puts messages on an iSeries Websphere MQ Queue for core system processing.

This application puts tens of thousands of messages on the iSeries MQ every day, runs round the clock, and has been reliable and resilient for 5 years.

Yesterday 5 messages (in a batch of 10) put on the MQ were not received from the iSeries side, yet on our side we appear to have got COMPLETION CODE MQCC_OK (value = 0)

Here is our code:

```
foreach (DataRow dRow in mqRequests.Rows)
{
     try
         {
          queuePutMessage = new MQMessage();
         queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
         queuePutMessage.WriteString(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.EDB_Message].ToString());                    
        queuePutMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING; // MQFMT_STRING = "MQSTR   ";

        /* Put message on Queue */
        pMQQueue.Put(queuePutMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);

        switch (pMQQueue.CompletionCode){

            case MQC.MQCC_OK:
            /* Message successfully PUT on return MQ */
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.MQ_Put_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Complete";
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
            break;

            case MQC.MQCC_WARNING:
            //  with warning
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Warning:\t" + pMQQueue.ReasonCode + '\t' + pMQQueue.ReasonName;
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

            /* Write to log */
            Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQWarning", Common.ActiveMQ, dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), "Exception");
             emailer.messageMonitorEmail(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), Common.ActiveMQ, "Warning:\t" + pMQQueue.ReasonCode + '\t' + pMQQueue.ReasonName);
             break;

             case MQC.MQCC_FAILED:

                 dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Error:\t" + pMQQueue.ReasonCode + '\t' + pMQQueue.ReasonName;
                 dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

                  /* Write to log */
                  Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQFAIL", Common.ActiveMQ, dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), "Exception");
                  emailer.messageMonitorEmail(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), Common.ActiveMQ, "Warning:\t" + pMQQueue.ReasonCode + '\t' + pMQQueue.ReasonName);
                  break;
                  }
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Error";
                dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
                /* Write to log */
                Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQException", Common.ActiveMQ, mqe.Message, "Exception");
                emailer.exceptionEmail(mqe);

                // Return nothing
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Error";
                dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
                /* Write to log */
                Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "Exception", Common.ActiveMQ, ex.Message, "Exception");
                emailer.exceptionEmail(ex);
                // Return nothing
                return;
            }
        }
```

so the process is:

1. Loop through all the messages to be put on the MQ
2. For each one, create an MQ Message and put it on the queue
3. Check the *Completion Code* **which is an INT and therefore DEFAULTS to ZERO, which BTW is = MQCC_OK**
4. Update the datatable, if the **Completion Code** = **MQCC_OK** we assume the message has been received with no error, otherwise we update the datatable for that message either with the MQ Warning message or the Fail message...

Now, in the .NET Framework an INT is a STRUCT, which defaults to 0, so if no COMPLETION CODE is sent by the MQ we seem to have an MQCC_OK

So, is it possible that a message is rejected or failed on the MQ, but because we have an INT defaulting to zero, we appear to have received an **OK** from the MQ? Surely the secure communication between the client/server with handshakes would prevent this?

If that is possible (however unlikely), how can we prevent this situation we have where I have marked 5 messages on the database as **Complete** based on MQC.MQCC_OK but the iSeries doesn't appear to have received them (again, code running for several years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be checking the CompletionCode of the MQQueue class when you do a put() method.  The code should look like:

```
foreach (DataRow dRow in mqRequests.Rows)
{
   try
   {
      outMsg = new MQMessage();
      pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
      outMsg.WriteString(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.EDB_Message].ToString());
      outMsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING; // MQFMT_STRING = "MQSTR   ";

      /* Put message on Queue */
      pMQQueue.Put(outMsg, pmo);

      dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.MQ_Put_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
      dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Complete";
      dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
   }
   catch (MQException mqe)
   {
      switch (mqe.CompletionCode)
      {
         case MQC.MQCC_WARNING:
            //  with warning
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Warning: CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + ' : RC=' + mqe.ReasonCode;
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

            /* Write to log */
            Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQWarning", Common.ActiveMQ, dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), "Exception");
            emailer.messageMonitorEmail(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), Common.ActiveMQ, "Warning: CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + ' : RC=' + mqe.ReasonCode);
            break;

         case MQC.MQCC_FAILED:

            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Error: CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + ' : RC=' + mqe.ReasonCode;
            dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

            /* Write to log */
            Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQFAIL", Common.ActiveMQ, dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), "Exception");
            emailer.messageMonitorEmail(dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Type].ToString(), Common.ActiveMQ, "Warning: CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + ' : RC=' + mqe.ReasonCode);
            break;
      }

      /* Write to log */
      Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "MQException", Common.ActiveMQ, mqe.Message, "CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + ' : RC=' + mqe.ReasonCode);
      emailer.exceptionEmail(mqe);

      // Return nothing
      return;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Error:\t" + ex.Message;
      dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
      /* Write to log */
      Common.logBuilder("WebSphereMQ --> putMessages <--", "Exception", Common.ActiveMQ, ex.Message, "Exception");
      emailer.exceptionEmail(ex);
      // Return nothing
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So do `MQC.MQCC_WARNING` and `MQC.MQCC_FAILED` throw MQ Exceptions?

Comment: It's the other way, a MQException will be thrown if the completion code is either MQC.MQCC_WARNING or MQC.MQCC_FAILED.

Answer (score 1):

If there was any error while putting message, an MQ exception would be thrown and you have the code to catch any `MQException`. So it's highly unlikely that client application missing errors sent down by the queue manager.

What version of MQ client are you using?

BTW the code you have after the Put call (shown below) will not execute in case of any exception. Also it is not required to check for the completion code in case `Put` call returns successfully, you can simply update database.

```
switch (pMQQueue.CompletionCode){

        case MQC.MQCC_OK:
        /* Message successfully PUT on return MQ */
        dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.MQ_Put_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
        dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Complete";
        dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
        break;

        case MQC.MQCC_WARNING:
        //  with warning
        dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Message_Status] = "Warning:\t" + pMQQueue.ReasonCode + '\t' + pMQQueue.ReasonName;
        dRow[(int)Common.InboundSQLFields.Last_Modified_Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

        /* Write to log */
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the behaviour you could see could be explained by the target queue having the setting DEFPRESP(ASYNC). This setting means that failures are not sent back to the application until it requests them, thus speeding up the sending of multiple messages over a client. It shouldn't be used if the application is not expecting that behaviour. It would be a quick check to tell whether this is set on in your system.

`DISPLAY QLOCAL(q-name) DEFPRESP`